# How to reset the value of my input items from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

I do simple volume calculations for shapes. Every time the user selects a different figure reset the select value to an empty field. I've tried reset() but it clears all options. I would like it to be done automatically, and not with a button each time I select a different option.

```
<form action="javascript:calculate()" onchange="javascript:upform()">

<label for="id_shapes">List</label>
<select id="id_shapes" > 
    <option value="sphere" selected>sphere</option>
    <option value="cone">cone</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<div id="id_inputs_sphere" >
    <label for="id_radius">radius</label>
    <input id="id_radius" type="number" min="0" step="any">
    <h2><em>formula: = 4/3*&Pi;*R<sup>3</sup></em></h2>
</div>


<div id="id_inputs_cone" hidden>
    <label for="id_radius2">radius</label>
    <input id="id_radius2" type="number" min="0" step="any">
    <label for="id_height2">height</label>
    <input id="id_height2" type="number" min="0" step="any">
    <h2><em>formula: = 1/3*&Pi;*R<sup>2</sup>*H</em></h2>

</div>

<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
<p id="id_output"></p>
</form>
```

```
<script>  

function upform() {
        
        document.getElementById("id_inputs_sphere").hidden = true;
        document.getElementById("id_inputs_cone").hidden = true;

        let shape = document.getElementById("id_shapes").value;
        switch (shape) {
            case "sphere":
                document.getElementById("id_inputs_sphere").hidden = false;
                break;
            case "cone":
                document.getElementById("id_inputs_cone").hidden = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    

    

function calculate() {

let shape = document.getElementById("id_shapes").value;
let area = 0;
switch (shape) {
    case "sphere":
        let radius = document.getElementById("id_radius").value;
        area = 4/3 * Math.PI * radius**3;
        document.getElementById("id_output").innerHTML = "result = " + area;
        break;
    case "cone":
        let radius2 = document.getElementById("id_radius2").value;
        let height2 = document.getElementById("id_height2").value;
        area = 1/3 * Math.PI * radius2**2 * height2
        document.getElementById("id_output").innerHTML = "result = " + area;
        break;        
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an event listener and some function that list every item you want to clear e.g:

the function:

```
const clear_inputs = ()=>{
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
      console.log(inputs);
      inputs.forEach(element=>{
      element.value = "";
      })
    }
```

Keep in mind that this particular function get all the inputs that have the type "number" so if you want to get other input types or an especific one you might want to specify those elements with their own id property.

the event listener:

```
 document.getElementById("id_shapes").addEventListener("change",()=>{
    clear_inputs();
    })
```

this event listener is triggered by your select box which list your shapes.

here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78ht1dmL/11/) if you want to check it out.

Comment: Can i also do this with <p id="id_output"></p>?

Comment: yes just include the element inside the clear function

Comment: u mean like that ? const clear_inputs = ()=>{
 let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]','p');
  console.log(inputs);
  inputs.forEach(element=>{
  element.value = "";
  })
}   document.getElementById("id_shapes" , "id_output").addEventListener("change",()=>{
clear_inputs();
})

Comment: after the for each just add `document.getElementById("id_output").innerHTML = "";` that will clear the P

Comment: I have a lot to learn... that was a too difficult task for me. Thank you for your time, thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

add id="myform" to form

```
<form action="javascript:calculate()" id="myForm" onchange="javascript:upform()">
       
       </form>
```

and look here

```
 function calculate() {

 let shape = document.getElementById("id_shapes").value;
 let area = 0;
 switch (shape) {
   case "sphere":
    let radius = document.getElementById("id_radius").value;
    area = 4/3 * Math.PI * radius**3;
    document.getElementById("id_output").innerHTML = "result = " + area;
    break;
case "cone":
    let radius2 = document.getElementById("id_radius2").value;
    let height2 = document.getElementById("id_height2").value;
    area = 1/3 * Math.PI * radius2**2 * height2
    document.getElementById("id_output").innerHTML = "result = " + area;
      break;        
}

    //add this line
  document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
}
```